# Workflow Fails to start

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, designer-workflow

I created a sharepoint designer workflow for list. Workflow fails for an item with error message '​ The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.'

When i look into the workflow settings i can see that workflow status as In Progress.

Since that workflow failed, i could not start any other workflow for that item. If i remove the workflow and added again, it works fine. But it is not a good solution.

How to detect when workflow fails and prevent this scenario??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create that Workflow step by step and to see on which step/item it breaks? In example, try to create it with one step, see if it breaks there, then add another step and so on. That way you can get a better insight on the problem.

Comment: I have only one step in my workflow. Also i am not getting this error every time. I can't trace at which scenario this error occurs. If it occurs, i can't proceed furthur.

Comment: There are number of things that could be the problem. For instance: [Time delay](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9951633/1340960), [Field Type](http://connect.nintex.com/forums/thread/23425.aspx), [Update List Item](http://antclegg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/workflow-could-not-update-item-possibly.html)

Comment: How to avoid these problems? If error occurs how can i proceed furthur?

Comment: On these links you have answers to each. I do believe that the problem is specific to each one and if you determine exactly where is the problem occurring in your case, you could probably solve it with one of these.

Comment: Can i terminate the workflow for an item using spservices?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603167/workflow-terminate-event-in-sharepoint) is something on the subject

Comment: I need to terminate the workflow using spservices or javascript?

Comment: You could try with `<xsl:text>javascript:StartWorkflow('myworkflow');</xsl:text>` with `StopWorkflow` instead of StartWorkflow and with your workflow ID instead of `myworkflow`, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: There is no method like stopworkflow.